# WebGL: Do I really have to change whole shader program to change only one shader?

Tags: webgl, shader

Do I understand right: if I only want to change vertex shader keeping the fragment one, I still have to create whole new shader program and set there old fragment shader and new vertex shader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you understand correctly.

Generally, you should create all the programs you will need at initialization time and keep them around, so that while rendering the only thing to do is `context.useProgram(p)`. useProgram is relatively cheap, but compiling and linking may be very slow (depending on the platform) and should not be done while rendering a frame.